# Is there a way to set up message moderation in Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Is there a way to get a feature in Exchange 2007 similar to message moderation in Exchange 2010 through the use of third party tools or otherwise? I've Googled things like "exchange 2007 outbound email approval" to no avail. We are working on getting Exchange 2010 implemented but I need an interim solution if at all possible. The reason for this is from a customer service perspective. I am willing to use a small process to be a smart host if needed. I would appreciate any suggestions or advice.

Edit: My apologies, I should have been more clear that I am trying to moderate/approve outgoing email *from* certain users, not moderate/approve email sent to a distribution group.

Answer (score 0):

I had a feeling this could be jerry-rigged with public folders, and this looks like [a good write-up](http://www.amset.info/exchange/groups-moderated.asp).  I'll run through it on my VM and comment here if I come up with anything new.

Comment: This is a great solution for receiving email to a distribution group, but I need to approve outbound email from certain people to any address (internal email excluded, but if we have to approve that for now as well I can live with that).

Comment: OUTBOUND, sorry that word just slipped right past my eyes. ;)  Still an interesting question.